# Error with scalar and ndarray in python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have small problem but I can't just find an easy answer.I feel stupid for asking it.

How can i multiply a scalar with a numpy.ndarray?

```
import fileinput,sys,re,csv,scipy,os,numpy,pylab
from collections import defaultdict
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as num
a = open("testt.txt", "r")
b=[ raw.strip().split() for raw in a]
c=np.array(b)
d=c.transpose()  
data=np.loadtxt("uu.txt",skiprows=1,dtype=None,delimiter='\t')
t1 = data[:,0]
t=(1/1000)*t1
s = data[:,9]
pylab.plot(t1, s)
pylab.xlabel('time (ms)')
pylab.ylabel('Zone height (mm)')
pylab.grid(True)
pylab.savefig('simple_plot')
pylab.show()
```

The error is in the line t=(1/1000)*t1 which gives me the error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'numpy.ndarray'. The text file uu.txt is an 60*60 matrix with an header as the first line.I can post it if its necessary.

Thanks

Comment: can you print `t1` just before the multiplication pls?

Comment: I put print t1 and this is the output : [  1.09000000e+02   2.19000000e+02   3.28000000e+02 ...,   4.95031000e+05
   4.95141000e+05   4.95250000e+05]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tad surprising. If `data` is a `ndarray`, then `t1=data[:,0]` is a `ndarray` too and you shouldn't have any problem multiplying it by an int.

Still:

- You could check the type of `t1` as well as its `.shape`.
- You can force `t1` to be a `ndarray` just in case: `t1=np.asarray(data[:,0])`
- I'm pretty sure you don't want to calculate `(1/1000)` but `(1./1000)` instead: `(1/1000)` is `0` by virtue of integer division...

Comment: (1./1000) dividing through this worked.I still dont understand the inital error. Why is 1/1000 too small? I tried  t1=np.asarray(data[:,0]) but it was the same error.

Comment: My theory: the `ndarray` wound up with the wrong `dtype` (e.g. `str`).  For example, `2*array([2],dtype=str)` gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'numpy.ndarray'`, an error which would be a lot more informative if it included the `dtype`..

Comment: As an aside, `from __future__ import division` fixes the integer division problem too (`1/2 == 0.5`). This is the default behaviour in Python 3.